# Save values in non activity class

Tags: java, android, class, save

I have a public class named "Values", I have values from my SettingsActivty stored inside this class. I have noticed that once I reset/close the app the values reset to default. I expected this to happen just like it does in activities.

Here is the code:

```
public class Values {

      //General Values
      public boolean vibrationEnabled = true;

      //Single Player Values
      public static float SPBackgroundNumber = 0;
      public static boolean resetScoreSP = false;

}
```

How would I be able to save these values and reopen them since it's not part of an activity?

Comment: you should use `sharedprefs` or `sqlite` to save your data, The values reset because it saves the data in the memory and when you close or reset the app the GC will clear the memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sharedPreferences to save and retrieve values.
To save values:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref=getSharedPreferences(FileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("key_value", data);
    editor.apply();
```

To retrieve values:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref=getSharedPreferences(FileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
name1=sharedPref.getString("key_value","default_value");
```

You need to declare `FileName` outside the class. Each data is identified the specified `key_value`

Comment: I was thinking I was going to use that. Do you know of any way to save the values with your method once the app is closed? onDestroy and other related methods don't work in non activity classes.

Comment: SharedPreferences stores the values even when you close the app. You can use it in any class. It is one of the easiest ways to store data.